# Insert X after 15 character in input mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

(XXX) XXX-XXXX xXXXX

I want insert a X symbol after every 15th character in input. I have a Business Phone input box. When a user is typing and reaches each 15th character, then jQuery will insert a hyphen (X).

For example: (999) 999-9999 x9999

I'm trying some codes and i think i'm so close to correct code but i have some problems. Here is my code sample;

```
$(document).delegate('#businessPhone', 'keyup', function(e) {
        var Textlength = $(this).val();
console.log(Textlength.length);
        if (Textlength.length >= 14) {
            //alert("if"+Textlength.length);
            $("#businessPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999 x9999");
return false;
        } else {
            //alert("else"+Textlength.length);
$("#businessPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
        }
    });
```

Code is working fine as aspected if user complete enter all characters.

But problem is user wants to remove characters the characters did not delete if character length reach 14 .

Comment: In console I get `TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function` what library did you include for the `.mask()` function?

Comment: Refer [http://jsfiddle.net/mykisscool/VpNMA/](http://jsfiddle.net/mykisscool/VpNMA/)

Comment: @sachin-k if maxLength is set to 14 in the html, then the problem here will not be touched, right? Since he wants a X after every 15th character

Comment: did you try putting in a ? at the beginning of the mask string. "(999) 999-9999? x9999". Also can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Just remove "maxlength" attribute in html and add `if ($phone.val().length === 15) {
    $phone.val($phone.val() + ' x');
   }` condition in if condition in that jsfiddle example

Comment: Do Textlength.length >= 15

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$('#phone-number', '#example-form')

 .keydown(function (e) {
  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
  $phone = $(this);

  // Auto-format- do not expose the mask as the user begins to type
  if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
   if ($phone.val().length === 4) {
    $phone.val($phone.val() + ')');
   }
   if ($phone.val().length === 5) {
    $phone.val($phone.val() + ' ');
   }   
   if ($phone.val().length === 9) {
    $phone.val($phone.val() + '-');
   }
            if ($phone.val().length === 15) {
    $phone.val($phone.val() + ' x');
   }
  }

  // Allow numeric (and tab, backspace, delete) keys only
  return (key == 8 || 
    key == 9 ||
    key == 46 ||
    (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
    (key >= 96 && key <= 105)); 
 })
 
 .bind('focus click', function () {
  $phone = $(this);
  
  if ($phone.val().length === 0) {
   $phone.val('(');
  }
  else {
   var val = $phone.val();
   $phone.val('').val(val); // Ensure cursor remains at the end
  }
 })
 
 .blur(function () {
  $phone = $(this);
  
  if ($phone.val() === '(') {
   $phone.val('');
  }
 });
```

```html
<form id="example-form" name="my-form">
    <label>Phone number:</label><br />
    <!-- I used an input type of text here so browsers like Chrome do not display the spin box -->
    <input id="phone-number" name="phone-number" type="text"  placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```